# What are different types of weights of an aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-design, weight-and-balance

When looking at different aircraft's specifications or in POHs/AFMs, there are several different weights of the aircraft mentioned (e.g. maximum take-off weight, maximum landing weight, operating empty weight).

What do they mean and how they are different?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The different terms represent different weights or masses<sup>1</sup>. For each flight, the weights are taken into account for several reasons.

A brief description about these is below:

**[Manufacturer's empty weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manufacturer%27s_empty_weight) (MEW)**
Also called *Manufacturer's Weight Empty (MWE)* or *Licensed Empty Weight*

It is the weight of the aircraft "as built" and includes the weight of the structure, power plant, furnishings, installations, systems and other equipment that are considered an integral part of an aircraft.

This excludes any baggage, passengers, or usable fuel<sup>2</sup>.

**[Zero-fuel weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-fuel_weight) (ZFW)**

This is the total weight of the airplane *and* all its contents (including unusable fuel), but excluding the total weight of the usable fuel on board.

As a flight progresses and fuel is consumed, the total weight of the airplane reduces, but the ZFW remains constant.

Maximum zero fuel weight (MZFW) is the maximum weight allowed before usable fuel and other specified usable agents (engine injection fluid, and other consumable propulsion agents) are loaded.

**[Operating empty weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_empty_weight) (OEW)** (Roughly equivalent to *basic empty weight* on light aircraft)

It is the basic weight of an aircraft including the crew, all fluids necessary for operation such as engine oil, engine coolant, water, unusable fuel and all operator items and equipment required for flight but excluding usable fuel and the payload.

**[Payload](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payload)**

It is the carrying capacity of an aircraft. It includes cargo, people, extra fuel. In the case of a commercial airliner, it may refer only to revenue-generating cargo or paying passengers.

**[Maximum takeoff weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_takeoff_weight) (MTOW)**

This is the maximum weight at which the pilot of the aircraft is allowed to attempt to take off<sup>3</sup>.

**[Regulated takeoff weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_takeoff_weight) (RTOW)**

Depending on different factors (e.g. flap setting, altitude, air temperature, length of runway), RTOW or *maximum permissible takeoff weight* varies for each takeoff. It can never be higher than MTOW. More information is on [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/44144/65).

**[Maximum landing weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_landing_weight) (MLW)**

This maximum weight at which an aircraft is permitted to land<sup>3</sup>.

The following image depicts takeoff weight components.

[image: Weights]
[*<sup>Image Source</sup>*](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Takeoff_weight_diagram.svg)

**[Maximum ramp weight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_ramp_weight) (MRW)**
*also called maximum taxi weight (MTW)*

It is the maximum weight authorized for maneuvering (taxiing or towing) an aircraft on the ground.

**[Aircraft gross weight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_gross_weight)**

It is the total aircraft weight at any moment during the flight or ground operation. This decreases during flight due to fuel and oil consumption.

---

<sup>1</sup>: As [mentioned (below in comments by SentryRaven)](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/what-are-different-types-of-weights-of-an-aircraft/12957?noredirect=1#comment28101_12957), several recent references use the term *mass* instead of *weight*. Having a Physics background, I tend to agree and know the difference between [weight and mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_versus_weight). I did not use *mass* as most of the references I included referred mass as weight. However, using correct terminology, all the weights mean mass. Thanks [SentryRaven](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/572/sentryraven) for pointing it out.

<sup>2</sup>: **What is the different between usable fuel and unusable fuel?**
*Usable fuel* is the fuel on board an aircraft that can actually be used by its engines. The small amount of fuel that cannot be drained from the tanks is the *unusable fuel*. For calculation of range, usable fuel is used. For weight and balance total fuel (usable + unusable) is used.

<sup>3</sup>: This restriction is due to structural, design or operational limitations.

Comment: AFAIK, they are no longer called weights but masses. The PPL training and examination material no longer uses MTOW but only MTOM: maximum take-off mass. [The skybrary also refers to MTOM](http://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Maximum_Take-Off_Mass_%28MTOM%29). Maybe leave a little remark in your otherwise very nice answer?

Comment: Also: +1 for image attribution and going Q&A style. ;)

Comment: Also related (and alluded to above) are the two most common "load" figures: *Useful Load* (the maximum gross takeoff or operating weight minus the operating empty weight), and *Payload* (what the aircraft can carry in cargo/passengers/personnel when loaded with the fuel required to make the planned trip).

Comment: @SentryRaven Since the U.S. is still (foolishly in my opinion) not using the metric system as our standard, I doubt that we will anytime soon use M instead of W since pounds are a unit of force, not mass. Also, I think the SKYbrary entry could be better written. As it is now, it would likely be interpreted as saying the aircraft's mass in pounds does not vary by altitude when, in fact, it does ever so slightly. The change, of course, is insignificant for aircraft weight purposes.

Comment: I believe MLW should refer to footnote #3, so I changed that. Please revert if I'm incorrect

Comment: @Terry, As far as I can tell, "pound" is a unit of _mass_ (defined as 1 lb = 0.45359237 kg)  and there is a "force pound", abbreviated lbf, that is a unit of force defined as 1 lbf = 1 lb × _g_ (_g_ is [gravity of Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth)), allowing people to be sloppy with their dimensions.

Comment: @JanHudec We may be looking at a generational thing. As I remember both my high school and college physics (1950s and 1960s), we were taught that in the English (Imperial?) system that the unit of mass was the "slug", the unit of force the "pound". The equivalent metric units were the Kilogram and the Newton. There was no mention of a "force pound."

Comment: @Terry, I think it's more a domain thing. ["Engineering"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Engineering_Units) system has pound for both mass and weight and live with _g_ coming up in Newton's second law, ["Gravitational"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Gravitational_System) system uses pound for force and slug = lbf·s²/ft for mass and ["Absolute"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_English_System) system uses pound for mass and poundal (pdl) = lb·ft/s² for force. The first is most common, but impractical for physics, which is why the other two are used there.

Comment: @Terry, also note that the metric system actually has similar set of variations with units like [kilopond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilopond) = kg·_g_ and even [hyl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyl_(unit)) = kilopond·s²/m, but these systems have fallen into disuse and SI became almost universal except for few uses of [CGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centimetre-gram-second_system_of_units), which is just scaled by powers of 10, and various natural units in particle physics and cosmology. While in imperial both mass-pound and slug are widely used.

Answer (score 11):

Read this from left to right, from detailed to generalized. Boxes on the right sum up the separate items which they run across.

[image: diagram of mass definitions]

The maximum landing weight is what the manufacturer has certified for landings. Generally, this is MTOW minus some fuel.

Note that every manufacturer has his own standard and might draw the lines between the different weight groups differently. Say, for one the engine quadrant is part of the propulsion system, whereas the other sees it as part of the control system.

Answer (score 4):

Lets see if I can make it more simplified.

The aircraft has:

- **Basic Empty Weight (BEW)** is the weight of the aircraft "as built" and includes the weight of the structure, power plant, furnishings, installations, systems and other equipment that are considered an integral part of an aircraft before additional operator items are added for operation.
- **Dry Operating Wieght (DOW)** BEW + Weight of Crew (Pilot + Cabin including their bags) + Pantry
- **Operating Weight (OW)** DOW + Takeoff fuel (i.e. Ramp Fuel - Taxi fuel)
- **Maximum Zero Fuel Weight (MZFW)** DOW + Payload (anything put on the aircraft that generates revenue to the company, e.g. passenger, baggage, cargo, mail and fret)
- **Maximum Taxi Weight (MTW)** MZFW + Ramp fuel
- **Maximum Takeoff Weight (MTOW)** MZFW + Takeoff fuel, or MTW - Taxi fuel
- **Maximum Landing Weight (MLW)** MTOW - Trip Fuel

Answer (score 1):

Max landing weight is in reality mzfw plus some fuel in the wings which will not cause structural failure upon touchdown.
For example an aircraft carrying max fuel for transatlantic flight must dump fuel when returning for landing due to an emergency,this procedure will ensure that the wings of that airplane won't break upon touchdown .

Otherwise good answers over all.

Comment: Wrong. Your ZFW can be well below MZFW but you still have a Max Landing Weight to contend with — more fuel in the wings than being at MZFW in that case.  The two limits are separate limits that have to be observed, and are only somewhat related.

Answer (score 0):

In military aviation both a Normal Take Off Weight and a Maximum Overload Take Off Weight are sometimes quoted, for the C130J these figures are 155,000 lb and 175,000 lb respectively.