# What is RTOW and how is it different from MTOW?

Tags: aircraft-performance, weight-and-balance

Please explain what is RTOW, and what is the difference between RTOW and MTOW. Is there a link between the RTOW and the Weight and Balance Manual?

Comment: What have you found so far? Related on PPRuNe: [MTOW and RTOW](http://www.pprune.org/tech-log/485813-mtow-rtow.html)

Comment: Related if not duplicate: [What are different types of weights of an aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12956/65)

Comment: @Farhan I don't think that question mentions RTOW? [This one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/44131/62) does, but only indirectly and it doesn't give a definition.

Comment: @Pondlife Yes, you are right. I added it there too.

Answer (score 8):

Google gives you the answer without even clicking any links:

https://www.google.com/search?q=RTOW

> **MTOW** is a hard limit regardless of other considerations and is tied up
>   with the basic aircraft certification basis.
> **RTOW** is the limiting
>   takeoff weight calculated for a particular runway under particular
>   specified conditions

**M**aximum **T**ake **O**ff **W**eight - The maximum weight in which an aircraft can ever take-off, under any circumstances.

**R**egulated **T**ake **O**ff **W**eight - The maximum weight in which an aircraft can take off from a particular runway under specific conditions (winds, weather, specific aircraft configuration, etc,). For example, runway 29 at KXYZ airport with ambient temp of 20° C. This can get as specific as you wish.

Of course $RTOW \le MTOW$.

Comment: In addition, there is no direct relation between the RTOW and the weight and balance manual (WBM), other than that limits specified in the WBM might impose a restriction which the RTOW would have to consider.